# Dropdownlist selected Value Sometimes returns text

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a dropdown list on my form with Integer Values set and displaying text. When I run the following code to display the Value and then associated text, I find that the text is displayed in as value when it is not supposed to. Any work around to this please?

function OnddlChanged(dropdown)
{

```
if( dropdown != null)
{
    var selindex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
    var selvalue = dropdown.options[selindex].value;
    var seltext = dropdown.options[selindex].text;
    document.getElementById('<%=Hidsel Key.ClientID %>').value = selvalue;
    alert(document.getElementById('<%=Hidsel Key.ClientID %>').value);
    alert(seltext);
}
```

}

Comment: how are you binding the data to the dropdownlist?

Comment: How come you have a space in the control name 'Hidsel Key'? Surely that is not allowed. Or is that a typo?

Comment: Binding on the backend is done on callback and that seems to work fine with all integer values applied. 

The space is from posting it here. Has nothing to do with actual code.

Comment: do you indicate what is the DataValueField and DataTextField?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do here but the result of your code will indeed alert the text value of your dropdown list.

In your js function **selvalue** will hold the text associated with the selected item of your dropdownList. Its this text value that you are then assigning to the value of the dom element thats returned from `<%=Hidsel Key.ClientID %>`

So when you call alert - its the text value you will see.

Comment: Yeah. For some reason it switches between text and integer as value. Not certain why.